# Porting OpenTK Windows app which uses GameWindow to Android using Xamarin?

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin, xamarin.android, opentk

I have an existing OpenTK application written in C#, which uses `GameWindow` class for the main window, `OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL` for graphics and `OpenTK.Input`.

**Question:** What would I have to change to be able to cross compile for *Windows* and *Android* at the same time?

*(estimating the costs of doing so)*

1. Naturally changing `OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL` into corresponding `OpenTK.Graphics.ES30*` API seems unavoidable. Fortunately OpenGL calls are already behind a thin-wrapper.
2. What else? Is this even possible?